# Android - App with layouts only - without controllers

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, ionic-framework

I'm programming an app in Android.

My client needs a 'dummy' like application, I mean, an app with all layouts but just navigable, without the actual controllers or activities, just navigate through layouts. By clicking buttons, but just pass to the other layouts without executing java or whatever code.

My question is, is this possible in AndroidStudio?

Or should I generate another kind of graphical app in order to accomplish this?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: We're using Pop for that: http://popapp.in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question (as I understood it) is no. You have to have activities to have an android app that will function. You could create a very rudimentary set of activities to do what you want.

However, if you are simply trying to create a mockup of what the app will look like for your client, I suggest using a tool like [FluidUI](https://www.fluidui.com). This will allow you to layout the general look and feel of your app without any actual code required.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thank you, yes it is something like this yea, a mock up of layouts, this app looks awesome, but, do you know an open source or free alternative?

Comment: Depending on the size of your app (I think the limit is 10 different screens), you can use FluidUI for free. I think [Proto.io](https://proto.io) also has a good bit of free functionality as well. If neither one of these work, I suggest just googling around for a tool that best fits your needs.

Comment: I'm trying Proto.io thank you, going to search and write back

Comment: Thank you ryguy for your input :), i'm using www.lucidchart.com

Comment: Awesome! I'll have to check that one out myself next time I need to put together some mockups.